# How to schedule a function?

Tags: java, android

I have a function that would like to be executde at 00:00am, 08:00am and 16:00pm. (every 8 hours).

How can I achieve this?

I have do some google and searching, but I can't find the solution.

I had tried the following code, but it doesn't work. Please help. Thanks.

```
        try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("2013/02/13 16:00:00");

        TimerTask updateProfile = new Controller(context);

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, date, 28800); //28800second == 8 hour

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: try AlarmManager with WakeLock,

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The program will call the function "updateProfile" continuously. But what I want is just call that function 8 hours per 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use & RND over `Service, AlarmManager, PendingIntent & Intent` and their work combination.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AlarmManager class to scedule a task for particular time, there are lots of example of alarammager, [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) period should be in milliseconds, 8 hrs = 28800000

2) Locale.ENGLISH makes no difference, remove to avoid confusion

3) You start date is in the past, when you start the timer it will run all skipped schedules. If you dont want it check that TimerTask.scheduledExecutionTime() is not in the past, eg

```
        public void run() {
            // truncate time to hours
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() / 3600000 * 3600000;
            long t2 = scheduledExecutionTime() / 3600000 * 3600000;
            if (t2 >= t1) {
                ...
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a new concept for me. I don't know it will re-run all skipped schedules.

Comment: Can you explain more how to avoid running all skipped schedules? I just want the function run only one time after the specific timer.

Comment: added an example how to skip old schedules